# New static page does not display data after "npm run build" in Next.js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

With an Editor I send some post's data to the server to display posts on the web. the problem is when the web is on production it does not show the new page but after I run `npm run build` and restart the server it shows the new page.

this is the code for getStaticPaths :

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({ query: GET_ARTICLES });

  const paths = data?.allArticles?.map((article) => ({
    params: {
      articleId: article?.slug,
    },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

Do I need to run `npm run build` every time I write a new post?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I need to change `fallback: true` to `fallback: 'blocking'` and add `revalidate: 10` to `getStaticProps`